# How much should I override readObject() writeObject(), in java?

Tags: java, inheritance, serialization

Seems an strange question, but look at this simple code:

```
public class Father implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    String familyName = "Josepnic";
    String name = "Gabriel"
    void writeObject (ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException{
        out.writeObject(familyName);
        out.writeObject(name);
    }
    void readObject(ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        familyName = (String) in.readObject();
        name = (String) in.readObject();
    }
}
public class Child extends Father{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    String name = "Josep";
    void writeObject (ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException{
        out.writeObject(name);
    }
    void readObject(ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        name = (String) in.readObject();
    }
}
```

I don't know if Child should also wirte the family name of his father or it would be automatically written? (I say this because father has a writeObject(), itselsf but I don't know about the treatment of Java Serialization).

Maybe a good suggestion is

```
public class Child extends Father{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    String name = "Josep";
    @Override
    void writeObject (ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException{
        super.writeObject(out);
        out.writeObject(name);
    }
    @Override
    void readObject(ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        super.readObject(in);
        name = (String) in.readObject();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you writing these methods in the first place? And why don't you test it?

Comment: Since it is a common question, I would like to present it on the web for others search

Comment: As you see, I my self have suggested an answer in the question

Comment: yeah right. Then answer your own question with the results of your test.

Comment: I almost know that my suggestion works; but, I also seek for a better suggestion.

Comment: My suggestion would be to avoid writing these methds in the first place.

Comment: Father needs serialization because it maybe written separately.

Comment: Serialization doesn't need you to write any method. Only to implement the Serializable interface. You create a Father, or a Child instance, write it to an ObjectOutputStream, and everything is done for you. To read it, you call readObject() on the ObjectInputStream, and it creates and populates the Father or Child for you. Hence my question, that you didn't answer: why are you writing these methods in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void writeObject (ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException{
    out.writeObject(familyName);
    out.writeObject(name);
}
void readObject(ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    familyName = (String) in.readObject();
    name = (String) in.readObject();
}

void writeObject (ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException{
    out.writeObject(name);
}
void readObject(ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    name = (String) in.readObject();
}
```

It doesn't matter in the least ***what*** you put into these methods as posted, because none of them is ever called. They aren't `private`, as required by the Object Serialization Specification, so Serialization doesn't call them.

And given that they are supposed to be private, using `@Override` is futile as well.

As your code presumably works, you can conclude from that alone that you don't need to do this at all. Let Serialization do it for you.